# How to change cell width in React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I need to change cell width in using React Table library, but I fail with any idea of width change. I need to do it to make "Użytkownik/Rola" column closer, just near-by "Status"column. I don't want to use margin-left with negative value as it's generally not recommended solution.
Generally rendered width is bigger than provided in style={{}}
This is how it's implemented:

```
{
            Header: useTranslactionFunc('Status'),
            accessor: 'status',
            width: 40,
            minWidth: 40,
            Cell: (props: CellValue) => (
                <div
                    style={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                        marginLeft: '1.5rem',
                    }}
                >
                    {props.cell.value ? (
                        <PlayCircleOutlineIcon
                            style={{
                                color: theme.palette.success.main,
                            }}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <NotInterestedIcon
                            style={{ color: theme.palette.error.main }}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
            ),
        },
```

And here how it's rendered:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: did you try setting the width, maxwidth and minwidth of the div?

Comment: yes, not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the `width` property doesn't apply when using table layout. Try using `useBlockLayout` hook.